# Could not trigger bar button item with custom view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

In my iphone application,

I have a one navigation bar Image to set I have set it like this....

```
   if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]){

        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarReady.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *bbiLeft=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBack.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnBackPressed:)]; 
    [bbiLeft setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [bbiLeft setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:7.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=bbiLeft;
```

It appears like this...

[image]

I want to set its color as navigationbar's background

How??
Thanks..

Comment: Tried really hard to avoid using a custom view to position the UIBarButtonItem but reading the docs I found why `setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:` does not work for UIButtonTypeCustom. From Apple doc: `This offset is used to adjust the vertical centering of bordered bar buttons within the bar.` - notice *BORDERED*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the Answer...

```
/* Back Button setted*/    
    UIButton *btnBack=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnBack setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 51,16)];
    UIView *backModifiedView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:btnBack.frame];
    [btnBack setFrame:CGRectMake(btnBack.frame.origin.x, btnBack.frame.origin.y+7, btnBack.frame.size.width, btnBack.frame.size.height)];
    [backModifiedView addSubview:btnBack];
    UIBarButtonItem *bbiLeft=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backModifiedView];
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=bbiLeft;



/* Arpit */
//set Navgation Bar.   
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]){

        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarReady.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the tintColor to clear doesn't work, you should pick a color that matches the bar background.

Also, you may need to set the tintColor of the UINavigationBar, not the tintColor of the UIBarButtonItem itself, as the navigation bar is responsible for tinting it's own button items.